Is there a continuous bijective mapping of $R$ into a compactum
I wonder if there are generally no bijective, continuous mappings of the form $$f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow K$$ if $K$ is a topological compact space.$$$$ My considerations I realize that the inverse function must not be continuous in this case, since $\mathbb{R}$ itself is not compact. As far as I know, there is also no theorem stating that the inverse must be continuous in such cases. The case $K \subset \mathbb{R}$ is also trivial, since in that case the $K$ would have to be bounded. Now in the case that $f$ could never reach the minimum of $K$ in finite time, since it is injective. I have also considered the sphere $S^1\subset \mathbb{C}$ with the mapping $t \mapsto \exp(2\pi i t)$, but this is only bijective from $[0,1)$.

We can modify the example of the continuous bijection $[0, 1) \to S^1$ slightly; namely, thinking of $\mathbb{R}$ as an open interval $(0, 1)$, it admits a continuous bijection to a compact subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ obtained by taking an open interval in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and bending the ends so that they approach the interval itself. It would be tedious and unenlightening to write down an explicit such bijection but I don't know a good way to draw a good picture online. Here's a terrible picture:

You could also take $K$ to be a wedge $S^1 \vee S^1$ of two circles, so we are thinking of, say, the open interval $(-1, 1)$ as the wedge of $(-1, 0]$ and $[0, 1)$ at $0$.

You can take $f:(-1,1) \to \Bbb R^2$ given by $f(t)=(\sin(\pi t), \sin(2\pi t))$ to make your example more concrete.
